# How to trust an invalid certificate in Big Sur / Safari 14

Tags: macos, safari, security, keychain

Since installing Safari 14, I can't find a way of trusting an invalid SSL certificate (either expired or set up for the wrong hostname).

I used to be able to click on the address bar and then trust that specific certificate but can't find a way to do that in Safari anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note: Don't do this for sites you don't trust!**

This might not be the simplest solution, but it's the only one I could come up with (thanks to https://serverfault.com/questions/139728/how-to-download-the-ssl-certificate-from-a-website# for explaining how to download the certificate). Assuming we want to trust `https://test.com/`

1. Download the certificate by running this in the Terminal:

```
echo -n | openssl s_client -connect test.com:443 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > /tmp/test.cert
```

2. Add it to your Keychain

```
open /tmp/test.cert
```

3. Add it to the System Keychain

[image: Add it to the System Keychain]

4. Find it in the Keychain, double-click it and trust it:

[image: Trust the certificate]